# How to count the number of commas in a text box using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Upon clicking a submit button, I would like to do some client side validation to ensure there are fewer than 5 commas in a text box with the class of submit-btn.  I can use javascript, jquery and/or regex here.

What code should I place within this function?

```
$('.submit-btn').on("click", function() {
  << WHAT GOES HERE? >>
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like homework? I'd probably take the length of the string and subtract the length of a modified string in which I've replaced all of the commas.

Comment: Not homework - just trying to limit the number of tags someone can enter in a text box, which are separated by commas. I just wrote it that way to make it clear exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use regex to find the number of times the string `,` occurs in the textbox value.  It prints whether or not it is valid (having less than 5 commas).

```js
$("#validate").click(function () {
  console.log(($("#textboxInfo").val().match(/,/g)||[]).length < 5)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textboxInfo" />
<button id="validate">less than 5 commas?</button>
```

## Automatically responding to user input

In this particular situation, I'd prefer to have live validation.  This can be accomplished by using the `input` event.

```js
$("#textboxInfo").on('input', function () {
  var isValid = ($(this).val().match(/,/g) || []).length < 5;
  $(".isValid").html(isValid ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textboxInfo" value="I really love ,,, commas!" />
<div class="isValid">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Your second suggestion of automatically responding to user input worked perfect for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`Split` the value of the input box and `filter` out `,` and check the length of it

```js
$('.submit-btn').on("click", function() {
  var getNumbers = $('#testBox').val().split('').filter(function(item) {
    return item === ','
  }).length;
  console.log(getNumbers)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='testBox'>
<button class='submit-btn' type="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this [Comma Counter](http://jsfiddle.net/ru6yvrce/1058)

`$('button').on('click',function(){
  var counter = ($('div').html().match(/,/g) || []).length;
 $('.result').text(counter);
 }
)`/

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove everything that is not a comma [`[^,]`](https://regex101.com/r/ITne32/1), replace that with an empty string and count the length of the string.

```js
$('.submit-btn').on("click", function() {
  var nr = $("#tbx").val().replace(/[^,]/g, "").length;
  console.log("Fewer than 5 commas? " + (nr < 5 ? "Yes" : "No") + " there are " + nr + " commas.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='tbx'>
<button class='submit-btn' type="button">Click</button>
```